# Pygame2exe not executing my game

Tags: python, pygame, exe, py2exe

I made a game called "Fish Food" with Python 2.7.6

When executing pygame2exe:

```
running py2exe
c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution
option: 'dist_dir'
warnings.warn(msg)
```

That returns error: bundle-files 1 not yet supported on win64

I am running Windows 8, 64 bit. If it is a problem of compatibility, is there any way for me to create an executable for my game (I used pygame) so that people who don't have python on their system can play it?

I have the script and it is incredibly long (and hard to format it on the website). But, it's just this: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe, but modified to load "FishFood.py" and the new dist folder "c:\python27\games\fish food\dist\"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was annoying, but I somehow figured it out to get my game to become a .exe. Didn't even use the long pygame2exe script.

1) Make sure latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package is installed
(not sure if my troubles were from that before). And make sure you have py2exe installed.

2) if your code has "None" as a font somewhere, change it! It could be anything besides None!

```
self.font = pygame.font.font(None,32)
```

change to

```
self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",32)
```

3) Setup.py code:

```
# setup.py, put in same folder as src
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['Game.py'])
```

4) Change file associations for .py from whatever editing program you use to python.

5) Go to cmd, change directory to your game folder, and then launch setup.py withpy2exe:

```
cd c:\python27\YOURGAMESRC\

setup.py py2exe
```

6) Copy all folders containing files that are used in the game (sprites, sounds, fonts, etc)

7) For installation instructions, extract all files and then click the .exe file to play and it worked for me.